# What is the significance of a Blood Moon in Judaism?

Tags: calendar, blood, moon

Is it true that the appearance of a Blood Moon is an omen in Judaism? And why it happens to be coinciding every time with a Jewish holiday since quite a while? I would like to know about the facts and seek authentic information on this notion if it carries significance.

FYI:

http://earthsky.org/space/what-is-a-blood-moon-lunar-eclipses-2014-2015

http://unitedwithisrael.org/the-blood-moon-and-jewish-destiny/

Comment: It's not true that this is a particular omen. The reason it often occurs on Jewish holidays is because blood moons occur during a full moon which is always on the 15th day of the lunar month. The Jewish holidays Pesach and Sukkot occur on 15th day of their respective months.

Comment: @Daniel, it stinks if you forgot your yontif candles, though (due to the decreased quantity of available light).

Answer (score 2):

We ascribe significance to lunar eclipses (Sukkah 29a), of which blood moons are a subset. The reason they occur so often on Jewish holidays is probably because we have holidays on or around the full moon (+- 2 days) half the months of the year: Sukkos, Tu b'Shevat, Purim (and Purim Katan), Pesach, Shivah Asar b'Tamuz, Tu B'Av. Blood moons, as well as all lunar eclipses, can only occur on full moons.

Comment: When you say "we only ascribe significance to lunar eclipses (Sukkah 29a), not blood moons", aren't blood moons a subset of lunar eclipses? Your statement precludes that.

Comment: I don’t believe they are, actually. Blood moons are refraction of sunlight; lunar eclipses are complete blockages thereof.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think a lunar eclipse is but a blood Moon is just a term for a tetrad of total lunar eclipses. See the link above and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_eclipse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64423/discussion-between-robev-and-donielf).